# Cannot access 'NgbNavLink' before initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ng-bootstrap, angular13

I am trying to test a component containing a component from **ng-bootstrap**, in **Angular 13**  using **Jest** and get the following error: `Cannot access 'NgbNavLink' before initialization`.

I have a component **MyComponent** which is using a **NgbModal**. I just want to create the test for this component, so I need to import **NgbModule** in my test. However, the import doesn't seem to work as I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/app/pages/kafkaconnect/kafkaconnect.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Cannot access 'NgbNavLink' before initialization

      2 |
      3 | import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent.component';
    > 4 | import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
        | ^

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.mjs:6651:991)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/pages/kafkaconnect/kafkaconnect.component.spec.ts:4:1)
```

Here is my test class:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent.component';
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      imports: [ NgbModule ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am using **Angular 13**, **ng-bootstrap 11.0.0-rc.0** and **bootstrap 4.6.1**. I know that these versions are very recent but I don't get any error serving or building my application, though.

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.3
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1300.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.0.3
@angular-devkit/core            13.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.0.3
@angular/cli                    13.0.3
@schematics/angular             13.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.4.4
```

Finally, I am using **jest 27.3.1**. As I am using Angular, I have configured **jest-preset-angular** following [this documentation](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular).

Any lead on why I'd get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seemed to be with **ng-bootstrap 11.0.0-rc.0**. Upgrading to **ng-bootstrap 12.0.0-beta.4** fixed the issue.

Comment: Sadly, version 12 comes with bootstrap 5 which has a lot of breaking changes. Is there any fix yet for version 11 (bootstrap 4)?

Comment: Hi @coaxial! From what I saw in the doc, version 12 supports bootstrap 4. Indeed, I left my version of bootstrap to bootstrap 4 and did not notice any issue.

Comment: Thanks @Gaetitan. I was trying to figure this error out myself, didn't realize it was just a version issue with ng-bootstrap. Updated and it fixed my tests failing on GitHub Actions with this error.